# Can't figure out why my ROT13 converter works with lowercase but it doesn't work with uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, function, if-statement, rot13

I can't figure out why my ROT13 converter doesn't work with uppercase letters.
It works with lowercase letters.
I've been trying to find the issue for a while now but with no luck..
Thanks for your help.

Here's the code

```
var rot13 = str => {

  let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  let alphabetUp = alphabet.toUpperCase();
  let ci = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    let index = alphabet.indexOf(str[i]);


    // for symbols
    if (!str[i].match(/[a-z]/ig)) {

      ci.push(str[i])
      // for letters A to M
    } else if (str[i].match(/[A-M]/ig)) {
      //lowercase
      if (str[i].match(/[a-m]/g)) {
        ci.push(alphabet[index + 13])
        //uppercase (doensn't work)       
      } else if (str[i].match(/[A-M]/g)) {
        ci.push(alphabetUp[index + 13])
      }
      // for letters N to Z
    } else if (str[i].match(/[n-z]/ig)) {
      //lowercase
      if (str[i].match(/[n-z]/g)) {
        ci.push(alphabet[index - 13])
        //uppercase (doensn't work)       
      } else if (str[i].match(/[N-Z]/g)) {
        ci.push(alphabetUp[index - 13])
      }
    }

  }

  return ci.join("");
}
```

Comment: `let index = alphabet.indexOf(str[i])` -- alphabet contains only lower-case letters. When will an upper-case letter give you anything other than -1 here?

Comment: Use `alphabet.indexOf(str[i].toLowerCase())`

Comment: You shouldn't use the `i` modifier when testing whether the letter is uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: And you don't need the `g` modifier when just testing whether a string matches a regexp.

Comment: You don't need regexes, you should only loop over required string and make temporary variable lowercase, move it and then check if the original character was uppercase or not with `character === character.toUpperCase()`, this should do the trick easily

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot for your explanation.  I really couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by adding 13 to index and using modulo 26 to get a new index and then check if the original letter was uppercase or not. Try this

```js
const rot13 = str => {
  let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  
  let newstr = [...str].map(letter => {
    let index = alphabet.indexOf(letter.toLowerCase());
    if(index === -1) {
      return letter;
    }
    index = (index + 13) % 26;
    return letter === letter.toUpperCase() ? alphabet[index].toUpperCase() : alphabet[index];
  })
  
  return newstr.join("");
}

console.log(rot13('hello'))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a way simpler solution than the one I was creating. I didn't think of using "% 26" in order to get the index value.